How to use container in WSL 2, without installing the Hyper-v feature?

OS: Win 10 Entreprise 22H2 build 19045

Hyperviseur: VMware® Workstation 17 Pro


Is it possible to install WSL on a Windows client, without installing the Hyper-v feature?
My problem is that I use VMWare Workstation Pro, for my labs. And that now I would like to use Docker desktop on my machine to host my containers.
But unfortunately docker deskop complains that I don't install Hyper-V, but that's normal because it's not possible to have 2 hyervisor type 1 on the same host.
Do you have any ideas for me to bother my local containers? Maybe without docker desktop, but I'll need some light :-)

VMWare 17 should have no problem running alongside Hyper-V..

At work we are not allowed to use Docker Desktop because of the license, but honestly I think pure Docker in a VM (including in WSL) is perfectly fine. You probably don’t need the UI.

There is no way to use Docker Desktop to run Linux containers on Windows without Hyper-V. It needs to either run a Linux VM itself (the default setup IIRC), or have a WSL2 environment it can work with (which in turn requires Hyper-V (techincally ‘Windows Hypervisor’, but that’s just the name MS has chosen to use for the interface). In fact, you can’t use it to run native Windows containers on Windows without Hyper-V either, because that would require the ‘Containers’ feature, which also depends on Hyper-V.
This leaves you with a couple of options:

Set up a proper Linux VM in VMWare and install Docker there. This is likely to be your easiest option, and is also likely to be the best option from a learning perspective.
Set up a Windows VM in VMWare with nested virtualization support enabled, and install Docker Desktop in that. This is going to have horrible performance (Windows does not virtualize well, and Hyper-V does so even worse), but would mean you don’t have to deal directly with Linux.
Set up your computer to dual boot an install of Linux, and install Docker there. This would get you the best possible performance for the containers, but they would not be usable at the same time as your VMs or your Windows system.


For point 3, I guess they could install VMWare Workstation Pro on Linux alongside Docker. Docker on Linux does not need virtualization (except, apparently, if you use Docker Desktop…).

WSL2 is literally a Hyper-V virtual machine, thus it requires Windows Hypervisor to be present. You can't make it run on VMware.
According to VMware docs, Workstation Pro 15.5.5 (or later, I assume?) supports using the Windows Hypervisor instead of its own hypervisor, under "Host VBS Mode".

in fact most hypervisor nowadays support Hyper-V, including VMWare and Virtualbox

Unfortunately, while recent VMware Workstation does support using Hyper-V as a hypervisor, there's a noticeable performance hit especially with anything that needs graphics (incl. browser engines). So you really have to make a choice here: stick with WSL1 (no hypervisor required), or use WSL2, enable Windows Hypervisor Platform and eat the perf hit on VMware.
